# Activity drop down list not displaying activites

Tags: activities

I have a number of custom activities set up, all of which are reserved and enabled.

[image: activity]

However they are not showing up on the new activity drop down when recording a new activity.

[image]

Any ideas on how to make them appear in the drop down (they do appear in the filter by activity type dropdowns)

Comment: the activities i am trying to see in the dropdown are all those marked as (NA)  Reminder sent, Pertinent Findings etc

Comment: What version of civi?

Comment: version 4.6.4.  These previously show before we upgraded from 4.5.8.  If I create the activites from afresh they do display, but then I have two set of activiees labelled the same (hence prefixing the ones that could not display as (NA)

Comment: This appears to be a bug. Has it been reported? How do we report bugs?

Answer (score 3):

Use phpMyAdmin or the api explorer to inspect those records in the db and look for differences between the old activity types which are not showing, and the new ones that are. In particular, check the `filter`, `is_optgroup` and `is_active` fields. This is how to do it in the api explorer:

[image: Api Explorer]

Comment: Thank you Coleman - i will pass to our techies, delving into PHP slightly beyond my abilities.

Comment: Ok. FYI the api explorer is a gui not a command-line tool. You'll find it in the Help menu under "developer". Just click the buttons like I showed you in the screenshot and you'll get the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using latest version of civi please upgrade to the latest version where I could find all the activity in the drop down box

I guess this got fixed in the latest version - I couldn't find NA in latest version (demo site)

Comment: Hi Ramesh - you would not find any starting with (NA) as these are custom activities.We are on version 4.6.4  (Wordpress)

Comment: hi Catherine - did u find a way to list those activity?

Answer (score 0):

If your Activities set to be used only for Cases then I don't expect them to show in the dropdown. Are they set for Cases or for Contacts or for Cases and Contacts?

Comment: The activity types that Catherine mentions - those beginning "(NA)" - show as component = Contact in her screen shot of activity type options.