# Why are some Activity Types with component = Contact hidden, e.g. "Inbound Email"?

Tags: activities

In some contexts, the list of Activity Types is filtered so that some are hidden. I'm not referring here to filtering out Activity Types defined for CiviCase only: I'm just considering those whose component = Contact (`civicrm_option_value.component_id IS NULL`).

Examples of contexts where some Activity Types are hidden:

- Actions button on contact summary
- New Activity drop-down on Activities tab
- New Custom Field Set -> Used For

Examples of standard Activity Types that are hidden:

- Inbound Email
- Inbound SMS
- Outbound SMS

I and others have seen cases where other activity types become hidden that shouldn't be, e.g. [Activity drop down list not displaying activites](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/activity-drop-down-list-not-displaying-activites).

This can be inconvenient in the following use cases:

- User wishes to record manually an email that they received. I have seen users work around this by defining a new activity type, e.g. "Record inbound Email".
- User wishes to define a custom field set for one of the hidden activity types. As discussed in [Is there a way to add a custom field to the Inbound SMS activity type?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/826/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-custom-field-to-the-inbound-sms-activity-type?rq=1), it's possible to add the custom field set using the API in this case - but that's not very user-friendly.

The mechanism by which they're hidden appears to be the `filter` field in the `civicrm_option_value` table: if this is set to 1, the activity type is hidden.

The point of my question is to establish...

(a) The rationale for hiding some activity types: I guess it's because these aren't expected to be created manually, so it's to reduce clutter in the Actions menu etc. E.g. "Inbound Email" is used for automatically-processed inbound emails.

(b) Why they are hidden in New Custom Field Set -> Used For: perhaps again to reduce clutter but as this is back-end, I'd argue those using it should be able to select from all activity types here.

(c) For a user wishing to record manually an email that they received: whether it's better practice to define a new activity type or change the "filter" field in the civicrm_option_value table for "Inbound Email".

CiviCRM 4.6, 4.7; CMS-agnostic issue but using Drupal 7.